# How i can start Trading My Token

Tags: blockchain, tokens, private-blockchain, cryptography

I have created token also its live on BSCSCAN , how I can start trading on it.

I tried via pancakes but there I have to deposit BNB for LP is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

you need to deposit at least one other coin, to create a trading pair on bsc(pancakeswap).
I does not have to be BNB if i remebmer correnctly. But you need to trade the token for something right? thats why you need to make a LP pair (Yourtoken/BNB).

Of course you could just give the tokens out and someone will eventually create an pair if they believe in your coin-

Comment: if someone buy my token and his money will be add in my LP what if i remove his money and still there left my provided LP will he able to sell it?